# How to delete a field from one CRM 2013 solution when another solution is built on top of that

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have two Dynamics CRM 2013 solutions:

```
base
special
```

special is built on top of base. That means that base defines some customizations that special needs and special defines some more customizations.

Now I want to delete a field (base_relatedobjects) from both solutions. It is defined in the base solution, so I deleted it there. I export that as managed and import that to the CRM with the special solution. After publishing the field is still there and it is managed, thus not deletable.

How can I delete fields like that?

Thanks and cheers

Arne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove a field from a deployed managed solution.  The fact that you have another managed solution built on top is actually irrelevant in this situation.  Your only options are to uninstall and re-install the managed solution or to leave the field as is.

**Update:**
It is possible to remove managed solution components through a bit of trickery called a holding solution nicely described here:
https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmthinkdynamics/archive/2014/09/25/how-to-delete-an-old-component-from-your-managed-solution-in-crm-2011-2013

Comment: That means I have to uninstall the base solution (managed) from the CRM with the unmanaged special solution. Since the special solution depends on the base I have to uninstall the special solution first. This equals deleting the organization and creating a new one. Before reinstalling the special solution I have to manually remove all references to the field "base_relatedobjects". I was hoping for an easier and cleaner solution, but thanks anyways.

Comment: A nice example of when unmanaged solutions are easier to work with than managed.  In unmanaged, you just delete the field in each environment and call it a day.